# jQuery autocomplete to html form

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have tried implementing an autocomplete on a form, it returns one value to one field but now I am trying to return the entire JSON to different HTML fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

//autocomplete
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 1
});

});
</script>
```

Retrieves the data as

```
[{"id":"13","firstname":"Eddie","surname":"Vedder","department":"Administration"}]
```

How can I make them appear in each input in my html form??

Answer (score 0):

You can select all input type text of your HTML file this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

       //autocomplete
       $("input[type='text']").autocomplete({
          source: "search.php",
          minLength: 1
       });

    });
</script>
```